# Dead of Winter Exiled Player

Tags: dead-of-winter

In Dead of Winter does an exiled player still draw a crossroads card?  Does the player on his right draw a Crossroads card the the exiled player?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the exiled player still draws a crossroads card and the player on the right still draws one for him/her.

Since they can't have any survivors in the colony, they can't vote on any cards that require survivors in the colony.

One of the designers clarified this in a reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/2kt5fn/dead_of_winter_question_probably_dumb/